# Recursive interface definition combined with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, interface, typescript-generics

I just ran into the situation in which I have some nasty nested data which I would like to describe with typescript interfaces.

Let's first look at a data sample

```
const d = {
    callbacks: { 
        x: { cb: (data: number) => {} },
        y: { cb: (data: string) => {} }
    },
    foo: {
        callbacks: { 
            z: { cb: (data: boolean) => {} }
        }, 
        bar: { /* .... */ }
    },
    baz: { /* .... */ }
}
```

Note: each level has a `callback` (which is required) key and some random keys (like `foo` and `bar`). Also note that the argument for the functions can be anything!

The results from my attempt to create interfaces for this data structure are:

```
interface DataItem<T> {
   cb: (data: T) => void;
}

interface Data {
   [key: string]: DataItem | Data;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAAjISwOwFwUwE4DMCGBjOICS8C2AeAFQD4QBvUcKkNAIwC4QAKAE0cIEoQBeUgNwD2EFgG5KYAL7BxkWIlQYQAERQwU5GeADaAazgBPRgGcYCaAHMAuowBKcNAIQt8Js1HMAabHhAAfZaooxGJUUjIOUCYgLDwa1OBoKAA2SbToOkaMZCCa8SAAHlk0DMwsgYxQAK64tIhcvOQSIBIeufGG5MWMrOUgrhb1pGRNUnnNrWNIAgJZbdSJKWloGUVzYwBeRXTdZWqMtNNJcChQg43Na+AtOWNUaQhFAPQAVCAAdB9vIM+PF2OjVyAA)

[image]

Now I see 2 problems:

1) The `Data` interface doesn't say anything about the required key `callback`
2) The `Data` interface uses `DataItem` which requires an argument

Any guidance on where to go from here would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the most reasonable concrete type to represent your data is something like:

```
interface Callbacks {
  [k: string]: { cb: (d: any) => void };
}

interface Data {
  callbacks: Callbacks;
  [k: string]: Callbacks | Data;
}
```

The main differences here from what you did:

- `Callbacks` isn't strongly typing the parameter to the `cb` function/method of its subproperties.  It uses `any` to allow anything.
- `Data` has a required `callbacks` property of type `Callbacks`, while other properties can be `Callbacks | Data`.  I know that you'd probably prefer other properties to be just `Data`, but unfortunately when you use a [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) you need to make sure that all string-keyed properties match it, including the specific `"callbacks"` property.  There are ways to represent the tighter constraint, but they tend to be generic types, and not concrete ones.

Anyway this definition will accept your data:

```
const d: Data = {
  callbacks: {
    x: { cb: (data: number) => {} },
    y: { cb: (data: string) => {} }
  },
  foo: {
    callbacks: {
      z: { cb: (data: boolean) => {} }
    },
    bar: {
      /* .... */
    }
  }
};
```

but as I said, it will also accept some data you might want to prohibit:

```
const oops: Data = {
  callbacks: {},
  foo: { throwbacks: { cb: (x: number) => {} } } // hmm
};
```

See, `throwbacks` is not `callbacks`, but it is accepted because every property of `Data` can take a `Callbacks` value.  This might not be a huge deal for you.  I'm inclined to leave it as-is for now because prohibiting it will mean making `Data` a generic type you have to specify everywhere.

Another drawback here is that the type `Data` has a bunch of index signatures and an `any`, which make it forget about the specific inferred type of your object literal when you try to use it:

```
d.callbacks.x.cb(1); // okay
d.foo; // okay
d.callbacks.x.cb("1"); // oops, no error?
d.flop; // oops, no error?
d.foo.callbacks.z.cb(true); // oops, error?
```

What I'd suggest there, if you want to retain knowledge of your object literal but require that it conform to `Data`, is to use a generic helper function which accepts anything matching `Data` and returns its input without widening it:

```
const dataHelper = <D extends Data>(d: D) => d;
```

And use it like this:

```
const d2 = dataHelper({
  callbacks: {
    x: { cb: (data: number) => {} },
    y: { cb: (data: string) => {} }
  },
  foo: {
    callbacks: {
      z: { cb: (data: boolean) => {} }
    },
    bar: {
      /* .... */
    }
  }
});

d2.callbacks.x.cb(1); // okay
d2.foo; // okay
d2.callbacks.x.cb("1"); // error as desired
d2.flop; // error as desired
d2.foo.callbacks.z.cb(true); // okay as desired
```

---

We could stop there, but if you really want to tighten past the concrete `Data` type and if you don't mind complexity, we can make the helper force the type of its arguments to strictly match "has a `callbacks` property of type `Callbacks` and all other properties are of type `Data`":

```
type DataConstraint<T extends Data> = {
  [K in keyof T]: K extends "callbacks"
    ? Callbacks
    : T[K] extends Data ? DataConstraint<T[K]> : Data
};

const dataHelper2 = <D extends Data & DataConstraint<D>>(d: D) => d;
```

That `DataConstraint` is a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) type that represents the constraint that only the `"callbacks"` property should be of type `Callbacks`.  Let's see how it acts:

```
const d3 = dataHelper2({
  callbacks: {
    x: { cb: (data: number) => {} },
    y: { cb: (data: string) => {} }
  },
  foo: {
    callbacks: {
      z: { cb: (data: boolean) => {} }
    },
    bar: { // error! missing callbacks 
      /* ... */
    }
  }
});
```

Hey, it gave an error I missed... the `bar` property under `foo` is missing its required `callbacks`.  And we also prohibit the bad `oops` value from before:

```
const oops2 = dataHelper2({
  callbacks: {},
  foo: { throwbacks: { cb: (x: number) => {} } } // error! not Data
});
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJwDYYEaINYDOyA3gFDLIDaeAXMgWFKAOYC6dxyC2dAFACZ04IAJ4BKZAF4AfMgBuAe2D9kAXwDcpVaVKhIsRCgAicMHBLkumHPgJ10WXAkKaK1OgyYg29608LIAD7IJmaa2qQICiAMyIIhpuaSFhQIfrYclhQAHhxcPMgCiXQgAK4AttjQEjIkqmoANFnIInncfPzF9IwsNbLE9doUqk0UMAoKmRSp6c52KdMUAF5tBUVmdNgTGBDCfXVqzSPNuFBTi8gA9ABUyAB0D3fI15dHltoaOvx3aY62d9kftheABGMTqK6XZAKPBwESkb7jBQQy5QmFwhE-WaEAFA3gAIhB+PBkOhCgADgQGsgQApkNAoAooAB+TEwDAUlFoilUml0hlM1mIiZYv5zO5LPGMUoQEmosmU6kClk6KIxMAK+ahJILX42OYcY5jCZ5MAAC0ZAHd-PNOO1CrkaRUqlB9gM1B75WbyuUtJpItFYp0zAAJCAYcnQKTIAA8Rnp2UgIH4RG10gEdCM+34-rVQYATNHg3AwxHoLwyDMxYRzjlVh0umVKtUpP1BqNpq0SPkGxtul5mG7Bu8O0ja1Zq7bmst64Vi5ttrsQEPDosjdNTuOKDd7o9nq81+8tOCvvnRfqcYDuKC5WjYfD+GekVzofeEWe9TbcdfCcSX8rkDgIh+AgAhgCgCB+HfO52U5UkAKAuJQPAyDoKRc8v0la9pVlF90REQDgOQiCoJ0MAREjBIzFQQNGDgPQYwAFQTJMUyouBZGSSsqAAaWQUBkDwCARAUGBkEY9hkD4iBEwgZMiHxT9bHxZpmTQbECGaOhGMoHjWBYuS2O1ZA1O1Gj1SgejwCY3TWFkTNEj9VVaLiRJS0jKBC2SOMDPk9jkAAMnY8zPCssA42kdN4izVs4lzFz+AAZiLNzww8-MK0sJSDQWOtu3tdY4BKZ0W1qd11woLs7TWed+16WLypHSwx1yicLynC5kBWfKaq6LYFB2PYGuHNcOwoTdu3lZUAEJkHKYACDA7w2ptZBAF4NwBQPenK5bj3F43mGY94vVTUvNc0M0ugDLuOyms6lHE1u3NK0bVnXhHSbF0V0GeCoEZKBZtpDVtSOnQdCAA)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for this extensive explanation. Very nice. I have to take some time to study all the examples :)